# accessing vaadin data on the client side

Tags: javascript, gwt, raphael, vaadin

I would like to know if there is a way to access or expose the data that is managed by Vaadin on the client side. I.e. I am using some data on the server inside of a Vaadin application. In the UI, I would like to include a visualization widget that uses this data and leverages raphael.js. I suspect this is possible using the gwt graphics library, but it would imply creating a custom Vaadin widget which looks like a headf*ck. Isn't there a simpler way, something as straightforward as using plain javascript on the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just use plain JavaScript and expose the data from the server as a simple JSON resource that you would consume in the client using plain GET/POST request to that resource.

Adding JS to Vaadin apps can be done either by overriding a method from AbstractApplicationServlet or using a CustomLayout which includes the JS. And there’s of course the Window.executeJavaScript method as well for smaller snippets of JS code.

Not the Vaadin way of doing things, but totally doable.

Comment: Hi Jouni. I have implemented something different, and I would like to have your take on it (see my own answer below)

Answer (score 4):

I have created a widget with the following server-side API:

```
private Map<String,Object> attributes = new HashMap<String,Object>();

@Override
public void paintContent(PaintTarget target) throws PaintException {
    super.paintContent(target);

    for (String key : attributes.keySet()) {
        Object value = attributes.get(key);
        if (value instanceof Boolean)
            target.addAttribute(key, ((Boolean) value).booleanValue());
        else if (value instanceof Float)
            target.addAttribute(key, ((Float) value).floatValue());
        else if (value instanceof Double)
            target.addAttribute(key, ((Double) value).doubleValue());
        else if (value instanceof Integer)
            target.addAttribute(key, ((Integer) value).intValue());
        else if (value instanceof Long)
            target.addAttribute(key, ((Long) value).longValue());
        else if (value instanceof String)
            target.addAttribute(key, (String) value);
        else if (value instanceof Map<?,?>)
            target.addAttribute(key, (Map<?,?>) value);
        else if (value instanceof Object[])
            target.addAttribute(key, (Object[]) value);
    }

    // We could also set variables in which values can be returned
    // but declaring variables here is not required
}

public void resetAttributes() {
    attributes.clear();
}

public void setAttribute(String key, Object value) {
    attributes.put(key, value);
}
```

On the client side, I simply attach the resulting UIDL to the document.

```
public void updateFromUIDL(UIDL uidl, ApplicationConnection client) {
    this.client = client;
    paintableId = uidl.getId();
    shareVars(uidl, getElement());
}

public native void shareVars(UIDL uidl, Element element) /*-{
    var el = element;
    var ownDoc = element.ownerDocument;
    ownDoc.uidl = uidl;
    ownDoc.doGraphics();
}-*/;
```

Now in doGraphics() I can access the uidl data with uidl[1]["attname"]

Combining it with the IcePush widget, I get all the behaviour that I need and it all works beautifully.

I'm curious why this solution hasn't appeared before since it looks quite natural to me and I would be grateful if you could compare this technique with the ones you mention.

Comment: I understood from your initial post that creating a custom GWT component seems too complicated for your taste, but I stand corrected. I guess you were only referring to the GWT Graphics add-on (which I haven’t used).

Your solution looks fine.